# Error disabling serialEvent() for COM3 null

Tags: java, arduino, processing

In my project I am trying to read a RFID number and amount from Arduino and use Processing to update the database on local host. It gives output for the first time and then gives an error.

Arduino code:

```cpp
int count = 0;                                          // count = 0
                                         // character array of size 12 
char input[12];                                // character array of size 12 
String in;
boolean flag = 0;                                       // flag =0
void setup()
{
   Serial.begin(9600);          // begin serial port with baud rate 9600bps
}
void loop()
{
    if(Serial.available())
    {
        count = 0;
        while(Serial.available() && count<12)
        // Read 12 characters and store them in //input array
        {
            input[count] = Serial.read();
            count++; 
            delay(5);
        } 
        String input1= String(input);
        int value=20;
        String stringOne =  String(value); 
        Serial.print (input1 +String("r")+ stringOne + String( ";") + String("r"));
        //Serial.write(in);   
    }
}
```

My Processing code is:

```java
import cc.arduino. * ;
import org.firmata. * ;
import processing.serial. * ;
import de.bezier.data.sql.mapper. * ;
import de.bezier.data.sql. * ;
MySQL dbconnection;
Serial myPort; // The serial port
String inByte = " ";
String inByte1 = " ";
String str2;
int breaker = 0;
String rfid;
int Amount;
int count;
int length;
String cutString;
String rfid12 = "";
int amount = 0;
MySQL akshay;
String UniqueID;
//Sftp sftp;
int rupeescharged;

void setup() {
    // List all the available serial ports
    printArray(Serial.list());
    // Open the port you are using at the rate you want:
    ***myPort = new Serial(this, Serial.list()[0], 9600);    <--- getting error on this line my serialEvent() gets disable for this port 
    myPort.buffer(18);***
    String user = "root";
    String pass = "";
    String database = "akshay";
    // connect to database of server "localhost"
    akshay = new MySQL(this, "localhost", database, user, pass);
    if (breaker == 1) {
        Amountfinal(rfid12, amount);
    }
    //setup();  
    noLoop();

}

void draw() {

}

void serialEvent(Serial myPort) {

    inByte = myPort.readString();
    String cutString = inByte.substring(0, 18);
    String[] list = split(cutString, ';');
    // print(cutString);
    //print(list[0]);
    String input = list[0];
    String[] init = split(input, 'r');
    rfid = init[0];

    String amt = init[1];
    Amount = Integer.parseInt(amt);
    String rfid1 = rfid.substring(0, 12);
    //println(rfid);
    //print(Amount);
    Akshay(rfid1, Amount);

}

void Akshay(String rfid, int amount) {
    String rfid_1 = rfid;
    int amt = amount;
    rfid_1 = rfid_1.replace("\f", "@");
    rfid_1 = rfid_1.replace(".", "@");
    rfid_1 = rfid_1.replace("\b", "@");
    rfid_1 = rfid_1.replace("\n", "@");
    rfid_1 = rfid_1.replace("\t", "@");

    //   println(rfid_1);
    if (rfid_1.charAt(rfid_1.length() - 1) == '@') {
        rfid_1 = rfid_1.substring(0, rfid_1.length() - 1);
    }
    println(rfid_1);
    //print(amt);
    Amountfinal(rfid_1, amt);
    breaker = 1;
}

void Amountfinal(String rfid12, int amount) {
    String rfid = rfid12;
    println(rfid);

    int rupeescharged = amount;
    if (akshay.connect()) {
        // rfid= "123";

        akshay.query("SELECT * FROM userrfid");
        while (akshay.next()) {
            // replace "first_name" and "last_name" with column names from your table
            String s1 = akshay.getString("rfid");

            int s2 = akshay.getInt("pass");
            int s3 = s2 - rupeescharged;
            akshay.execute("UPDATE userrfid SET pass='" + s3 + "' WHERE rfid='" + rfid + "'");
            print(s3);

        }
    }
    //setup();
}
```

Comment: What error does it give you?

Comment: "Error disabling serialEvent() for COM3 null"
I am getting this error

Comment: On what line? Can you please post a [mcve]?

Comment: thax for response @Kevin Workman my system runs well when rfid number is send to processing from "Arduino" for first time, it also updates the "amount" in localhost database corresponding to RFID number. But when RFID number is send to processing for second time it gives me "Error disabling serialEvent() for COM3 null". Sry for bad english.

Comment: Your English is fine. But you're going to have to [debug](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/debugging) your program so you understand exactly what's happening in your code. We can't really help you do that because you're using specialized hardware here. Try to get rid of the dependencies on the external hardware and create a [mcve] that we can run without it to still see the error.